# how to understand Camera's properties like Position, Look Direction, Up Direction?

Tags: wpf, 3d, camera

I downloaded some sample from internet.
but the sharp always disappear when i changed any value of Position, or Look Direction, or Up Direction.
I can't understand these properties, can anyone help me?

what's relationship between these properties?
is there any sample to show these relationship?

Comment: Can you add more tags to your question? Probably the 3d tag would be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Position is a vector from the scene root(origin) to the camera.

Look direction is a unary vector positioned at the camera that points in the direction the camera is looking.

Up direction is a unary vector that points to "the sky", I mean, points in the direction the camera considers as "up". Normally you use a (0,1,0) vector here.

Look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170506171824/http://www.toymaker.info/Games/XNA/html/xna_camera.html) for more info.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've provided [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30691275/1648849) to a similar question with graphical explanation that might help others.

Comment: I'm not sure how this was marked helpful when it isn't even true?  There is a very big difference between lookDirection="0,-1, -1" and lookDirection="0,-.5,-1".

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 3-D Graphics Overview on MSDN, specifically [the section on cameras](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747437.aspx#cameras).