# Make Camera LookDirection look front face

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, camera

How to look at the front of `3D` Model in `WPF`?

I am confused to set X Y Z for LookDirection.

I don't know what happens when I set xyz and I don't know where camera is looking at. I don't know the same thing for `UpDirection`.

Below is my camera properties:

```
camera.Position = new Point3D(100, 100, 150);
camera.LookDirection = new Vector3D(-100, -100, -100);
camera.UpDirection = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
```

The problem is that camera is looking from behind.
Model is shown like cube below.

[image]

How to make it look front face?

Also please explain how to set xyz. i know what properties do but i cant imagine them.

I think X is from right to left.Y is depth. Z is up to down .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Imagine, instead of a camera, you're moving your head around in 3D space. then   `Camera.Position` is specifying where your head is located, `Camera.LookDirection` determines the direction you're looking at and `Camera.UpDirection` shows the orientation of your head. the following pictures clear things up for you.

In the first Image, Camera is centered on the +Z axis looking down to -Z axis and to your shape:

[image]

When you set `camera.Position` to for example (x=1, y=0, z=10) then camera position changes like this:

[image]

as a result, camera moves a little to the right and therefore you will see your shape at the left side of the view.

Now if `camera.LookDirection` gets changed to say (x=0, y=1, z=-1), then camera simply looks at the point (0,1,-1) like this:

[image]

---

**Important Edit:**

Based on DaveInCaz's comment, `LookDirection` is different from `LookAtPoint` 
(former property of `PrespectiveCamera` which was a `Point3D` rather than 
`Vector3D`).

`LookDirection` is actually equals to *"the point to look at"* minus *"camera position"*.

This means that in the above diagram, if we want the camera which is located in (1,0,10) to look at point (0,1,-1) then the `LookDirection` should be:

(0,1,-1) - (1,0,10) = (-1,1,-11).

---

And finally, `camera.UpDirection` determines where the top of your camera points at. In the following picture, setting `camera.UpDirection` to (-0.5,1,0) results in rotation of the camera counter clockwise:

[image]

I hope these pictures clear things up for you.

Comment: i marked it as answer yet because of nice pictures.however ill try to set camera position my self based on your explanation. thanks

Comment: you're welcome. [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23332/WPF-D-Primer) which contains source code along with a demo project could also be useful.

Comment: i got it right. thanks again for nice explanation.also i had to Transform camera with RotateTransform3D because model was build in different axis. `camera.Transform = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), 90));` i could never understand it without this ! thank you!

Comment: Based on this post I think the description of how LookDirection works may be incorrect... isn't it setting a direction vector explicitly, and NOT setting a "Look at point"? o https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ebooth/2005/12/06/wpf-perspectivecamera-lookdirection/

Comment: @DaveInCaz Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I've updated my post based on your comment.

Comment: NP and this helped to clarify my understanding as well, thanks